# Accessing object using method via this

Tags: javascript

could you help me out with this code?

```
var mac = {  
    notebook: "macbook",  
    desktop: "imac",  
    get_product: function (kind) {  
        return this.kind;  
    }  
}  

console.log(mac.get_product(notebook)); //ReferenceError: notebook is not defined
```

I expected "macbook" to log on the console.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: You've not defined a `notebook` variable anywhere. Did you mean to pass a string `"notebook"`? If so, it still won't work unless you do `return this[kind]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this is the code which will do what you're trying to do:

```
var mac = {  
    notebook: "macbook",  
    desktop: "imac",  
    get_product: function (kind) {  
        return this[kind];  
    }  
}  

console.log(mac.get_product('notebook'));
```

Looking at your original code:

```
var mac = {  
    notebook: "macbook",  
    desktop: "imac",  
    get_product: function (kind) {  
        // this.kind means mac.kind. You haven't defined mac.kind.
        // return this.kind;  
        // instead, you want to look up the value of the property defined
        // at kind.

        // [] allow you to dynamically access properties in JavaScript
        // this["<something>"] means "get me the property named <something>
        // but because the contents of [] are determined before the overall
        // expression, this is the same as return this["<something>"];
        // var prop = "<something>";  return this[prop];
        return this[kind];
    }  
}  
// notebook (without quotes) is interpreted as a variable, but there is no
// variable by the name "notebook".
console.log(mac.get_product(notebook));
```

Answer (score 0):

`notebook` is inner for `mac` so you cannot access it on `console.log(mac.get_product(notebook));`

Have a look at this article: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Answer (score 0):

Just like `get_product` function, the `notebook` parameter is also defined inside the variable mac - so you'll need to refer to it as `mac.notebook`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things up with this.

1. There's no such thing as 'notebook' (it's 'mac.notebook'),
2. There's no such thing as 'this.kind' (I presume you meant 'this.notebook').

   ```
   var mac = {  
       notebook: "macbook",  
       desktop: "imac",  
       get_product: function (kind) {  
           return this.notebook;  
       }  
   }  

   console.log(mac.get_product(mac.notebook));
   ```